# cs1660 cannot convert lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

After i searching and type this to save date and time but i faced this error CS1660
on code

```
this.lbl_NI_Time_Left.Invoke((Delegate) (() => this.lbl_NI_Time_Left.Text = this.fwacherNorthInLeftLane.CurrentTime));
```

Comment: Please post a [mre], including the exact error message (as text).

Comment: If that's windows forms `Control.Invoke` you're invoking, you almost always want to be looking at `Action` or `Func<T>` these days rather than the `Delegate` overloads.